# See all notes on iOS9

Tags: notes.app, ios

After the update to iOS9 which allowed notes to be in rich text, only the notes "on my iPhone" were converted to this new format. The notes associated with my gmail weren't. Before the upgrade, I could lump all notes together in one list so I didn't even need to worry where they were being stored. But now it looks like half the lists I use frequently are on my iPhone, and half are associated with my gmail. Is there a way in iOS9 I can put them all back in one list (e.g. see all)? Or even just convert all the plaintext gmail notes over to the new style?

Comment: I have the same issue, which is of course how I got here. I'd like a way to go back to the previous notes. I don't want any of the new features and the split folders is just plain annoying. Sigh.

Comment: @sdjuan not sure if this is also valid if you're not on iCloud Notes, but there's a toggle in `Settings → Notes` that says '"On My iPhone" Account' which should allow you to save everything into your preferred account by toggling it OFF.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the new style, then you need to put your notes into the iCloud Notes account, because it is a must that the server support this rich text format.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can move them all together on your phone by clicking edit and on the bottom left there is a Move All link. From each folder you can then move to the folder on your phone so they are all together. Sadly it does not allow you to move from the phone to say gmail, icloud or exchange notes but you can move those all onto your phone in the same folder. That's not what I want but hey at least it gets them together.

UPDATE: Although already on iOS 9 the above was before I upgraded to the new notes. Once on the new notes the move from my phone to icloud seems to have just made a copy as now I have them in both places. I actually wanted to move them all to my exchange account but that iss not an option. OK that is a glith in iOS 9 it just looked as if it was on both by the number of notes shown. When I went into the phone notes they were then empty and on exit from there the number dropped to zero. Still no way to move to exchnage or gmail but you can at least move everything to the cloud or the phone. Those seem to be your two options to have everything together.